# Is there a way to see what .php file created the output of a section of HTML viewed using F12 IE tools?

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm editing a Joomla template for a website and I'm using "Inspect Element" from the f12 tools to  find the location of various CSS selectors and their files which Is great.
What I can't do Is figure out which .php file Is responsible for a section of html output. All I can do is edit the HTML in the F12 console to preview any changes I'd like to make which is pointless.

I'm pretty new to all this so I'm not sure where I should be looking for information. Is their any data about the .php in the html file Itself ?

Comment: No there is not. If you want there to be, you need to make it work that way.

Comment: If you really don't know it, you could edit the view files 1 by 1 and see when something changes. Then you know what file your dealing with

Comment: Don't you have access to the php (template) files that output the HTML code ?

Comment: Ok.Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

No. The server won't sent any information about how the page was constructed to the client.

If you want that information then you need to expose it explicitly (e.g. by outputting HTML comments from each file you include and/or function  you run).

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT !!

First of all start with understanding server and client.
Who is server ?
Who is client ?
What is HTTP ?
Understanding about DOM

http://w3.org/DOM 
 
http://blog.bloc.io/frontend-vs-backend-web-development http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

here are some links that can help you for start.

Comment: In theory you can.I Just wanted to know If there Is a way to do so.